# Cannot see tables/views in Toad Scheme browser

Tags: toad

Upon Toad, I can query tables, but can't use Toad's schema browser to see, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does that schema (you're connected to) contain any tables or views at all? The fact that you can write queries might mean that you're selecting from **synonyms** (private or public) which don't belong to *you*.

Run the following query; it'll show you what you have on disposal in your own schema.

```
select object_name, object_type from user_objects order by object_type;
```

Then modify USER_OBJECTS to ALL_OBJECTS so that you'll see what you have access to (it'll show the owner as well):

```
select owner, object_name, object_type from all_objects order by owner, object_type;
```

It should help you find the reason why you don't see *anything* in the Schema Browser.